# How to implement multiple inheritance in delphi?

Tags: delphi, multiple-inheritance

I'm doing a full rewrite of an old library, and I'm not sure how to handle this situation (for the sake of being understood, all hail the bike analogy):

I have the following classes:

- `TBike` - the bike itself
- `TBikeWheel` - one of the bike's wheel
- `TBikeWheelFront` and `TBikeWheelBack`, both inherits from `TBikeWheel` and then implements the specific stuff they need on top of it

This is pretty straightforward, but now I decide to create multiple kind of bikes, each bikes having it's own kinds of wheel - they do the same stuff as a regular front/back wheels, plus the specific for that bike.

- `TBikeXYZ` - inherits from `TBike`
- `TBikeWheelXYZ` - inherits from `TBikeWheel`

And here is my problem: `TBikeWheelFrontXYZ` should inherit from `TBikeWheelXYZ` (to get the specific methods of an XYZ wheel), but it should also inherit from `TBikeWheelFront` (to get the specific methods of a front wheel).

My question here is, how can I implement that in a way that doesn't:

1. feel like a hack
2. force me to rewrite the same code several time

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Delphi does not support Multiple Inheritance. But classes can support / implement multiple interfaces and you can delegate interface implementation, so you can kinda simulate multiple inheritence.

Answer (score 17):

Use interfaces.  Something like this (Off the top of my head, based on your description.....)

```
type

  IBikeWheel = interface
    ...
  end;

  IXYZ = interface
    ...
  end;

  IFrontWheel = interface(IBikeWheel)
    ...
  end;


  TBike = class
    ...
  end;

  TBikeWheel = class(TObject, IBikeWheel);

  TBikeWheelXYZ = class(TBikeWheel, IXYZ);

  TBikeFrontWheelXYZ = class(TBikeWheelXYZ, IFrontWheel);
```

Then implement classes for the interfaces that do what the corresponding classes in your old (presumably C/C++) library does and instantiate them in the corresponding class's constructor.

Comment: When I try this, I get the _AddRef/Release/QueryInterface unimplemented error.

Answer (score 9):

Use polymorhism to implment each 'thing' as an object hierarchy in its own right and then add object properties to that object in turn. So, create a hierarchy of wheels, and a hierarchy of bikes. Then add wheels to bikes as fields in the ancestor bike object. See below.

```
  TBikeWheel = class
  TBikeWheelXYZ = class( TBikeWheel ) 

  TBike = class
    FFrontWheel : TBikeWheel;
    property FrontWheel : TBikeWheel
      read FrontWhell  

  TBikeABC = class( TBike)
    constructor Create;
  end;

  constructor TBikeABC.Create;
  begin
    inherited;
    FFrontWheel := TBikeWheel.Create;
  end;

  TBikeXYZ = class( TBike)
    constructor Create;
  end;

  constructor TBikeXYZ.Create;
  begin
    inherited;
    FFrontWheel := TBikeWheelXYZ.Create;
  end;
```

Comment: +1, containment often models reality much better than inheritance.

Answer (score 5):

A variation of Brian Frost's suggestion:

```
  TBikeWheel = class
  TBikeWheelXYZ = class( TBikeWheel ) 

  TBike = class
    FFrontWheel : TBikeWheel;
  protected
    function CreateWheel: TBikeWheel; virtual;
  public
    property FrontWheel : TBikeWheel
      read FrontWheel  
  end;

  TBikeABC = class( TBike)
  protected
    function CreateWheel: TBikeWheel; override;
  end;

  function TBikeABC.CreateWheel: TBikeWheel;
  begin
    result := TBikeWheel.Create;
  end;

  TBikeXYZ = class( TBike)
  protected
    function CreateWheel: TBikeWheel; override;
  end;

  function TBikeXYZ.CreateWheel: TBikeWheel;
  begin
    result := TBikeWheelXYZ.Create;
  end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically - you CAN'T. Delphi does not support multiple inheritance.

So left with that dilemma, the question is: could you possibly refactor that library in such a way that you can get away with using interface? Is the multiple inheritance mostly about functions and methods? If so - use interfaces. Delphi can support multiple interfaces on a class.

If the multi-inheritance is more about inheriting actual functionality in the classes, then you're probably looking at a bigger scale refactoring, I'm afraid. You'll need to find a way to break up those functional dependencies in such a way you can make it inherit from a single base class, possibly with some additional interfaces thrown in.

Sorry I can't provide an easy answer - that's just the reality of it.

Marc

Answer (score 3):

You can try to extract an interface, say IFrontWheel, out of TBikeWheelFront, so that it is a subclass of TBikeWheel but implements IFrontWheel. Then TBikeWheelXYZ inherits from TBikeWheel and TBikeWheelFrontXYZ inherits from TBikeWheelXYZ and implements IFrontWheel.

Then you can define a class TFrontwheel and give it the same methods as the interface, but now you implement them. Then TBikeWheelFront and TBikeWheelXYZ get a private member of type TFrontwheel and the IFrontWheel implementations of them simply delegate to the private member methods.

This way you don't have double implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative with newer versions of Delphi is to leverage generics in a compositional model.  This is particularly useful in the case where the multiple base classes (`TBarA` and `TBarB` in this example) are not accessible for modification (ie: framework or library classes).  For example (note, the necessary `destructor` in `TFoo<T>` is omitted here for brevity)  :

```
program Project1;

uses SysUtils;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type    
  TFooAncestor  = class
    procedure HiThere; virtual; abstract;
  end;
  TBarA = class(TFooAncestor)
    procedure HiThere; override;
  end;
  TBarB = class(TFooAncestor)
    procedure HiThere; override;
  end;
  TFoo<T: TFooAncestor, constructor> = class
    private
      FFooAncestor: T;
    public
      constructor Create;
      property SomeBar : T read FFooAncestor write FFooAncestor;
  end;

procedure TBarA.HiThere;
begin
  WriteLn('Hi from A');
end;

procedure TBarB.HiThere;
begin
  WriteLn('Hi from B');
end;

constructor TFoo<T>.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FFooAncestor := T.Create;
end;

var
  FooA : TFoo<TBarA>;
  FooB : TFoo<TBarB>;
begin
  FooA := TFoo<TBarA>.Create;
  FooB := TFoo<TBarB>.Create;
  FooA.SomeBar.HiThere;
  FooB.SomeBar.HiThere;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way, if you do not want to repeat the code several times and want a decoupled code.

```
type
   TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnTest: TButton;
    procedure btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
   private
      { Private declarations }
   public
      { Public declarations }
   end;

   TBike = class
   end;

   IBikeWheel = interface
      procedure DoBikeWheel;
   end;

   TBikeWheel = class(TInterfacedObject, IBikeWheel)
   public
      procedure DoBikeWheel;
   end;

   IBikeWheelFront = interface
      procedure DoBikeWheelFront;
   end;

   TBikeWheelFront = class(TInterfacedObject, IBikeWheelFront)
   public
      procedure DoBikeWheelFront;
   end;

   IBikeWheelBack = interface
   end;

   TBikeWheelBack = class(TInterfacedObject, IBikeWheelBack)
   end;

   TBikeWheelFrontXYZ = class(TInterfacedObject, IBikeWheel, IBikeWheelFront)
   private
      FIBikeWheel: IBikeWheel;
      FBikeWheelFront: IBikeWheelFront;
   public
      constructor Create();
      property BikeWheel: IBikeWheel read FIBikeWheel implements IBikeWheel;
      property BikeWheelFront: IBikeWheelFront read FBikeWheelFront implements IBikeWheelFront;
   end;

var
   Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

{ TBikeWheel }

procedure TBikeWheel.DoBikeWheel;
begin
   ShowMessage('TBikeWheel.DoBikeWheel');
end;

{ TBikeWheelFrontXYZ }

constructor TBikeWheelFrontXYZ.Create;
begin
   inherited Create;
   Self.FIBikeWheel := TBikeWheel.Create;
   Self.FBikeWheelFront := TBikeWheelFront.Create;
end;

{ TBikeWheelFront }

procedure TBikeWheelFront.DoBikeWheelFront;
begin
   ShowMessage('TBikeWheelFront.DoBikeWheelFront');
end;

procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   bikeWhell: TBikeWheelFrontXYZ;
begin
   bikeWhell := nil;
   try
      try
         bikeWhell := TBikeWheelFrontXYZ.Create;
         IBikeWheelFront(bikeWhell).DoBikeWheelFront;
         IBikeWheel(bikeWhell).DoBikeWheel;
      except
         on E: Exception do
         begin
            raise;
         end;
      end;
   finally
      if Assigned(bikeWhell) then FreeAndNil(bikeWhell);
   end;                                          
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Delphi does not support Multiple Inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest the following steps:

1. Inherit the `TBikeWheelFrontXYZ` class from either `TBikeWheelXYZ` or `TBikeWheelFront` (since in Delphi multiple inheritance is impossible as mentioned in the answers above).
2. Convert one of the parent classes `TBikeWheelXYZ` or `TBikeWheelFront` to class helper for the `TBikeWheel` class.
3. Add the class helper unit to the unit, where the `TBikeWheelFrontXYZ` class is declared.