# how to achieve Multiple inheritance in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am new in Delphi development.

I know how to implement single inheritance:

```
TDerClass = class(TBaseClass)
```

I am curious about how I can achieve multiple inheritance in Delphi

Comment: See [How to implement multiple inheritance in delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1276173/576719).

Comment: FWIW I regard inheritance with much suspicion. It's a greatly overused tool. As for multiple inheritance, it's very hard to come up with good use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi does not support multiple inheritance of implementation. It does support multiple inheritance of interface.

More detail can be found in the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Inheritance_and_Interfaces