# Is it possible to extend two or more classes with only one implementation?

Tags: delphi

I'm facing a problem that I think cannot be solved without some amount of code replication, but maybe I'm missing something.

This is my scenario:

```
TCommonAncestor = class (TSomeClass, ISomeInterface1, ISomeInterface2)

TAncestor1 = class (TCommonAncestor)

TAncestor2 = class (TCommonAncestor)

TMyClass1 = class (TAncestor1)

TMyClass2 = class (TAncestor2)
```

Given I can't modify nothing before TMyClass1/2 (the ancestors are Delphi classes, to be more specific I'm inheriting from FireDAC's Query/MemTable/StoredProc...), I need to implement a number of methods and properties common to all my inherited classes.
Obviously the interface isn't a problem, I can create a new IMyInterface that declares all my new methods and properties, and modify my class declarations like this:

```
TMyClass1 = class (TAncestor1, IMyInterface)

TMyClass2 = class (TAncestor2, IMyInterface)
```

But then I must implement every method on every derived class...

Is there a way to avoid duplicate so much code?

Comment: Unfortunately, Delphi does not support multiple inheritance.  Interfaces or a compositional model are your only choice.  Which version of Delphi?

Comment: Ops, I hadn't thought of seraching for multiple inheritance... I'm using Delphi XE6.

Comment: I've added a new answer to the duplicate question with another alternative that may suit your particular use case.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25160619/327083

Comment: Alternatively, if all you are worried about is replicating the interface implementations in each child class you can read a bit more about delegating interface implementations.  In this way you can have a common interface implementation class - see for example : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3483889/327083

Comment: Thank you J. Actually delegating interface implementation is more suitable for my needs. I have to create components that directly inherit from FireDAC ones, they must be usable as if a native FireDAC component was there, and sometimes in some generic code I use methods and properties from TDataSet on these components. Your answer to the duplicate question gives a very clean implementation technique, but I can't figure out how this can be applied to my scenario, given the constraint I've just mentioned.