# How to inherit multiple forms in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Say I have a Form A and Form B, I want to inherit both A and B in Form C, then I can see all the component from A and B.

Thanks.

Comment: not possible, you could refactor form A and for B into frames though.

Comment: I wonder what how this would work were implementation inheritance support by the language. How would the two different forms be combined?

Comment: [Delphi does not support multiple inheritance of classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1276220/7579632)

Comment: Not possible. But there is a frames mechanism. Look at the examples that might suit you.